# Sound doesn't work on 18.04 with Sound Blaster Z

Tags: sound, 18.04, soundcard, sound-blaster

The sound card is recognized, but there are only two ports enabled in the settings. The headphone jack is absent.

Comment: I unmuted everything in `alsamixer` to no effect. I'm at a loss.